# Cloudflare / SSL certificate expired. Как продлить?

Tags: ssl

У сайта отвалился SSL. При просмотре деталей сертификата пишет что сегодня сертификат истёк. Тариф Pro Website, настройки CDN месяца 3 не менялись. Просто истёк и всё как то. Пробовал включать/выключать SSL, менять тип FULL/Flex/OFF не помогает. Саппорт в ауте 8 часов нет ответа.

Кто сталкивался? Как заставить Cloudflare перегенерировать сертификат с новой датой expired?

Comment: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203446030-Why-am-I-getting-a-SSL-expired-error-message- проверьте что корневые сервера у домена прописаны правильно

Comment: NS стоять те что дал Cloudflare, 3 месяца ничего не менялось.